# Не пойму работу объекта в python. Pygame. Откуда беруться новые обьекты smallFish

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pygame

Имеется следующий код. И проблема у меня возникла с методом `eating` и `think` класса `smallFish`. При выполнения моего кода, мало того что рыбки поедат водоросли они еще и умудряються размножаться, не могу понять с чем это связанно. Логика поедание водросли: если вокруг есть водросль рыбка ее ест ( становиться на место водросли и старое место мы забиваем обьектом `place` а в новом месте уже эта рыбка - `smallFish`)

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
import random

width,height = 100, 50;
directions = [
    [-1,0],
    [1,0],
    [0,1],
    [0,-1],
    [-1,1],
    [-1,-1],
    [1,-1],
    [1,1],
    [0,0],
    ]

def derictionRandomazer(arr):
    random.shuffle(arr);
    return arr;

def addObjects(obj,objCount,count):
    while count <= objCount:
        x = random.randint(1,width-2);
        y = random.randint(1,height-2);
        if type(pond[x][y]) == Place:
            pond[x][y] = obj(x,y);
            pond[x][y].spawn();
            count += 1
    pygame.display.flip();

pygame.init();

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (width * 10, height * 10) )
pygame.display.set_caption("Life in Pond"); 

class Place:
    color = (52,152,219)
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y ;

    def spawn(self):
        square = pygame.Rect(self.x*10, self.y*10, 10, 10);
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, square);

class Stone(Place):
    color = (0,0,0);

class Seaweed(Place):
    lifePeriod = 40;
    color = (2,124,2);
    reproductivePeriod = 10;
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super().__init__(x,y);
        self.age = 0;

    def aging(self):
        self.age += 1;
        if self.age == self.lifePeriod:
            self.dying();


    def dying(self):
        pond[self.x][self.y] = Place(self.x, self.y);
        pond[self.x][self.y].spawn();
 

pond = [[ 0 for x in range(height)] for y in range(width)]

for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        pond[x][y] = Place(x,y);
        pond[x][y].spawn();

pygame.display.flip();
num = 0;

class smallFish(Seaweed):
    lifePeriod = 30;
    color = (0, 77, 255);
    reproductivePeriod =  5;

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super().__init__(x,y)
        self.age = 0;
        self.hunger =  8;


    def reproduction(self,obj):
        if self.age % self.reproductivePeriod == 0:
            for direction in derictionRandomazer(directions):
                new_x = self.x + direction[0];
                new_y = self.y + direction[1];
            if 0 <= new_x < width and 0 <= new_y < height:
                if type(pond[new_x][new_y]) == Place:
                    pond[new_x][new_y] = obj(new_x,new_y);
                    pond[new_x][new_y].spawn();

    def aging(self):
        self.age += 1;
        if self.age == self.lifePeriod:
            self.dying();

    def hungering(self):
        self.hunger -= 1;
        if self.hunger == 0:
            self.dying();

    def think(self,obj):
        for direction in directions:
            new_x = self.x + direction[0];
            new_y = self.y + direction[1];
            if 0 <= new_x < width and 0 <= new_y < height:
                if type(pond[new_x][new_y]) == Seaweed:
                    self.eating(self.x,self.y,new_x,new_y,obj);


        for direction in derictionRandomazer(directions):   
                new_x = self.x + direction[0];
                new_y = self.y + direction[1];
        if 0 <= new_x < width and 0 <= new_y < height:
            if type(pond[new_x][new_y]) == Place:
                self.swim(self.x,self.y,new_x,new_y,obj);

    def reproduction(self,obj):
        if self.age % self.reproductivePeriod == 0:
            for direction in derictionRandomazer(directions):
                new_x = self.x + direction[0];
                new_y = self.y + direction[1];
            if 0 <= new_x < width and 0 <= new_y < height:
                if type(pond[new_x][new_y]) == Place:
                    pond[new_x][new_y] = obj(new_x,new_y);
                    pond[new_x][new_y].spawn();

    def eating(self,x,y,new_x,new_y,obj):
            pond[x][y] = Place(x,y);
            pond[x][y].spawn();
            
            pond[new_x][new_y] = smallFish(new_x,new_y);
            pond[new_x][new_y].spawn();
            self.hunger =+ 1;
        
    def swim(self,x,y,new_x,new_y,obj):
        pond[x][y] = Place(x,y);
        pond[x][y].spawn();
        pond[new_x][new_y] = obj(new_x,new_y);
        pond[new_x][new_y].spawn(); 



addObjects(smallFish,1,0);
addObjects(Stone,50,0);
addObjects(Seaweed,1,0);


while True:
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            #  or type(pond[x][y]) == predatoryFish

            if type(pond[x][y]) == Seaweed:
                pond[x][y].aging();
                if type(pond[x][y]) == Seaweed :
                    pond[x][y].reproduction(Seaweed);
    


            if type(pond[x][y]) == smallFish:
                    pond[x][y].aging();
                    # pond[x][y].reproduction(smallFish);
                    pond[x][y].hungering();
                    if type(pond[x][y]) == smallFish:
                        pond[x][y].think(smallFish);


    pygame.display.flip();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема всетаки была в том, что я создаю новые обьекты, а не работаю с имеющимся, поэтому я просто добавил новую координату к "себе".

```
pond[new_x][new_y] = self;
pond[new_x][new_y].spawn();
```